# Changing object prototype

Tags: javascript

I have the following 2 functions:

```
function Dog() {}
function Cat() {}
```

I set `Dog.prototype = new Cat()`

I then create a `dog` instance:

```
let dog = new Dog();
```

Why is `dog instanceof Dog === true`. I understand why `dog instanceof Cat === true` because I just set it to `Cat`'s `prototype` but how is there still some reference to `Dog` `prototype` when it has been overridden even before the instance was created? How would I make make `dog instanceof Dog === false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in MDN docs

> The **instanceof operator** tests whether the prototype property of a
>   constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

That means `instanceof` will check the `prototype` property of the constructor with the `__proto__` of  the `Object`, not the value that `prototype` is holding. You can check this as following

```
console.log(Dog.prototype === dog.__proto__) // prints -> true
console.log(Dog.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(dog)) // prints -> true
```

What you are doing is merely changing the `prototypes's` `value. It still is the same property.

**Modified:**

Take a look at simplified implementation on `instanceof` method

```
function instanceOf(object, constructor) {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(object) === constructor.prototype;
}
```

Here, you can see that `instanceof` returns `true`, if reference of `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)` is equal to `constructor.prototype`. In your case `Dog.prototype` is `Cat`, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(dog)` is also `Cat`. That's why `instanceof` will always return true.

**Reference**

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Search for `Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === C.prototype`

Comment: I feel like I'm still not really getting it. `Dog.prototype === dog.__proto__` which I understand but `Dog.prototype` is `Cat`, so how is `dog` still `instanceof` `Dog`?

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: Wow, that is absurd. So if I did this: `function Rat() {} var cat = new Cat(); Rat.prototype = cat; Dog.prototype = cat;` then `dog instanceof Rat === true`

Comment: I guess `dog instanceof Rat === true` will be `false` in this case.

Comment: No, it is true!

Comment: You created `dog` first and then set the `prototype`. If you keep the order the same as my question, it comes out as `true`. See https://jsbin.com/jufutomoso/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160581/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-johanp).